# SQL query: can this be done without a nested query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The query below works but is very computational expensive (there are > 14k records); can this be done more efficiently (e.g. without a nested query)?
Basically it matches instances in the same table that represent a turn-on command (log1) with the first-to-follow turn-off command (log2).

```
SELECT log1.`deviceID`, log1.`timestamp` AS `on`, log2.`timestamp` as `off` 
FROM `HC2_log_raw` log1, `HC2_log_raw` log2 
WHERE log1.`newValue` > 0 AND log1.`oldValue` = 0 AND log2.`newValue` = 0 AND log1.`deviceID` = log2.`deviceID` AND 
    log2.`timestamp` = 
    (SELECT MIN(log3.`timestamp`) 
    FROM `HC2_log_raw` log3 
    WHERE log3.`timestamp` > log1.`timestamp` AND log3.`deviceID` = log1.`deviceID` AND log3.`newValue`=0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: 14k records aren't a lot. 
have you already had a look at the execution plan?
you might just need an index

Comment: did you use indexes on join conditioned columns ?

Comment: It won't help performance, but you should switch to explicit `join` syntax, it's ANSI standard since 1992!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use *JOIN* with *GROUP BY* and *MIN* function to archive your expected result

```
SELECT log1.`deviceid`, 
       log1.`timestamp`      AS `on`, 
       MIN(log2.`timestamp`) AS `off` 
FROM   `hc2_log_raw` log1 
       INNER JOIN `hc2_log_raw` log2 
               ON log1.`deviceid` = log2.`deviceid` 
                  AND log1.`timestamp` < log2.`timestamp` 
WHERE  log1.`newvalue` > 0 
       AND log1.`oldvalue` = 0 
       AND log2.`newvalue` = 0 
GROUP  BY log1.`deviceid`, log1.`timestamp`
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm and about 5 times as fast :) Thanks for all the other comments as well, I still do need to create proper indexes, which should make it even faster!

Comment: An index on deviceid and timestamp only improved speed by 20% btw

Comment: Have you tried to create index on also newvalue and oldvalue fields?

Answer (score 0):

check this out. afaik, `where` clause works better than join `on` condition.

```
SELECT log1.`deviceID`
    ,log1.`timestamp` AS `on`
    ,log2.`timestamp` AS `off`
FROM 
`HC2_log_raw` log1
inner join `HC2_log_raw` log2
on 
log1.`deviceID` = log2.`deviceID`
where
(
    log1.`newValue` > 0
AND log1.`oldValue` = 0
AND log2.`newValue` = 0
AND log2.`timestamp` = (
        SELECT MIN(log3.`timestamp`)
        FROM `HC2_log_raw` log3
        WHERE log3.`timestamp` > log1.`timestamp`
            AND log3.`deviceID` = log1.`deviceID`
            AND log3.`newValue` = 0
        )
)
```